Unbalanced Pi Pad attenuator circuit - circuit analysis - equation derivation
Reference books and online attenuator simulation tools use the following equations for a π-pad attenuator circuit of the form shown below (note that the names of R2R and R3​ are sometimes interchanged):

The final equations:
$$ R_1 = \frac{(K - 1) Z_1 \sqrt{Z_2}}{(K+1) \sqrt{Z_2} - 2 \sqrt{K Z_1} } $$
$$ R_2 = \frac{(K - 1) Z_2 \sqrt{Z_1}}{(K+1) \sqrt{Z_1} - 2 \sqrt{K Z_2} } $$
$$ R_3 = \frac{K-1}{2}  \sqrt{\frac{Z_1 Z_2}{K}} $$
The issue is that I haven’t been able to find the detailed computations or circuit analysis required to derive these equations. Despite searching online and consulting various old and new reference books, they only provide the final equations without any explanation of how they were obtained.
Naturally, I attempted the derivation myself by writing the circuit equations for the input and output impedances, as well as incorporating the attenuation factor K (see third equation), but I haven’t succeeded in reaching the final formulas.
Input Impedance (\$Z_{in} = Z_1\$):
$$Z_1 = \frac{R_1 \left( R_3 + \frac{Z_2 R_2}{Z_2 + R_2} \right)}{R_1 + \left( R_3 + \frac{Z_2 R_2}{Z_2 + R_2} \right)} $$
Output Impedance (\$Z_{out} = Z_2\$):
$$Z_2 = \frac{R_2 \left( R_3 + \frac{Z_1 R_1}{Z_1 + R_1} \right)}{R_2 + \left( R_3 + \frac{Z_1 R_1}{Z_1 + R_1} \right)} $$
Voltage Attenuation (\$K = V_{in} / V_{out}\$):
$$K = \frac{R_3 + \frac{Z_2 R_2}{Z_2 + R_2}}{\frac{Z_2 R_2}{Z_2 + R_2}} $$
My question is: Has anyone successfully derived the final equations for the π-pad attenuator, or does anyone know the assumptions or simplifications that were applied to arrive at them?
Thanks a lot !


Has anyone successfully derived the final equations for the π-pad
attenuator

I have done this for a taper pad and it was tortuous. I'm sure you can use some of the thoughts I had to help you with the pi-pad attenuator. In the end I made an online taper-pad tool: -

Below the image above there is the full derivation for the taper-pad attenuator. Hope it helps or at least inspires to help you solve it.
The method of solving for the taper-pad was to recognize that it could be made from two back-to-back L-pad attenuator and, of course, it's likely that the same applies to solving the pi-pad attenuator. L-pad derivation can be found here on my basic website: -

The derivation for the L-pad is also underneath the image above on the site.
